# Remotely waking up my desktop through WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, power

I have a desktop computer with a WiFi adapter in a PCI slot. (It is currently unfeasible for me to get an ethernet line into my room.)

1) Suppose I leave my desktop in sleep mode (Windows 7). Is it possible to configure it so that I could wake it up over the internet, say, on my phone far away or from my work computer?

2) What if the desktop was powered off? What are my options to configure it so that it can be powered on remotely under the assumption that there is a WiFi signal in the room?

UPDATE: After researching a bit, I think the conclusion is that wireless LAN cards in a PCI slot (as opposed to integrated into the motherboard) do not receive enough power to receive the magic packet in sleep mode. This is surprising since my wireless keyboard and mouse can wake the PC from sleep with no additional tweaking required. I'm now considering building a robotic arm that pushes my wireless mouse, but I really hope someone can come up with a better idea :/

Comment: It's surprising and unfortunate waking on wifi isn't more of a thing.

If you haven't considered distributing your network signal via Coax or power line, either of these approaches might be a feasible way to transmit the wake request. Both Coax and power line approaches have decent signal strength however based on reviews Coax seems to have better consistency and a stronger signal.

Answer (score 2):

There are few basic requirements that should match in order to perform a remote wake up of a machine using the available network connection.

1. Basically, the machine should always be connected to the wall power, so that 5 DC voltage is always available to wake up the machine using WOL feature.
2. Your motherboard should have WOL option
3. Enable the WOL option in the bios and necessary settings in the network adapter for wake up a machine.

Please refer the detailed information from the following URL and try to meet your requirement: http://www.howtogeek.com/192642/how-to-remotely-turn-on-your-pc-over-the-internet/